# Is it possible to have the same juju master node for multiple environments?

Tags: juju

Does each juju environment specified require its own master node, or will different juju environments share the same master node?

> **Moderator Note**: This was merged by mistake. Apologies. As merging can't be undone I've got egg on my face. Bryan if you'd please open a new question with the same subject in order to continue.